# Best use of a global struct variable in C

Tags: c, struct, global-variables

I have a global var struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int myvar1;
    int myvar2;
    int myvar3;
    ...
    int myvar10;
} t_myStruct myGlobalData;
```

I cannot avoid this global structures, so I have to use it.
I have three options to use it:

- Use the global var "as is" into any function. I.e.:

  ```
  int myFunc(void) {
      myGlobalData.myvar1 = ...
      myGlobalData.myvar10 = myGlobalData.myvar5 + ...
  }
  ```
- Declare a local pointer and use it:

  ```
  int myFunc(void) {
      t_myStruct * p;

      p = &myGlobalData;
      p->myvar1 = ...
      ...
      p->myvar10 = p->myvar5 + ...
  }
  ```
- Use local var and then copy to global struct:

  ```
  int myFunc(void) {
      t_myStruct localStruct;

      localStruct.myvar1 = ...
      localStruct.myvar10 = localStruct.myvar5 + ...
      myGlobalData = localStruct ;
  }
  ```

Could explain me what is best way in general and why?

Comment: They should really make it easier to put code-blocks between bullets. Now I understand why had to use the quote-blocks instead of code-blocks.

Comment: @Mystical you can also "double indent" the code blocks to join them to the list items

Comment: The third option is particularly risky.  Having two versions of the same data that are slightly out of date from one another is a recipe for nasty race conditions when you add complexity and have multiple pieces of code operating on the different versions of the data.

Comment: Your memcpy copies `myGlobalData` to `localStruct` - is that intentional!?  BTW `myGlobalData = localStruct ;` will copy a struct.

Comment: sorry, it is not intentionally. Is a mistake! Thanks for noticed it.

Comment: @Kyrol: So you should have corrected it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Choose more abstraction. If you can change the arguments to `myFunc`, then make its signature:

```
int myFunc(t_myStruct *arg)
{
    arg->myvar1 = ...
```

Now the function itself doesn't depend on the existence of a global variable at all. And the same for any other functions that need to operate on a `struct` of this type. If you must use a global variable then isolate the use of it *as much as possible*, i.e. use the global in as few places as possible.

If you can't change the function signature, I would choose the option from your question that is the most direct: the first. Just operate directly on the global variable.

Comment: Thanks! Just to know: you suggest me to use global var only when is strictly necessary ?

Comment: @Kyrol yes that's right, and when you use a global, limit its use as much as possible

Comment: @Kyrol: as this example shows, global variables can make code hard to re-use (if `myFunc` refers to `globalData` directly, then it can't be used as part of a different program that doesn't define `globalData`).  Ideally, functions and their callers should communicate exclusively through arguments, return values, and exceptions (if applicable); they should not share state through globals.  This makes it easier to re-use the function in another program.

Answer (score 2):

Of the three options you listed, IMO, the first one is the best. Just carefully use the global structure.

The first and second options are almost identical, but whenever you start using pointers unnecessarily things get obfuscated and people tend to make more mistakes.

The third option is just a bad idea. Now you expect every function to be sure to write back the data when they're done? What if function `A()` and function `B()` are both making edits to the global structure? `A()` puts back the data when it's done, then `B()` finishes second and overwrites `A()`'s data? Now you need additional protection mechanisms in place... just a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

First of all why is it so *unavoidable*?  Secondly why are those your only three options?

If you must access a global, your first option is not unreasonable - its already global, how much worse can it get?

Your second option is entirely pointless.

Your third option also has little merit, and the memcpy is unnecessary, you can assign a struct directly:

```
myGlobalData = localStruct ;
```

None of the solutions are advisable in a multi-threaded application.

So the answer is neither of the above.  Instead, if there is no real reason for not doing so, qualify the global as `static` so that it is invisible outside the module in which it is defined, then in that same module define appropriate access functions.

Even without the static declaration, the access functions are a good approach since you can validate arguments, ensure data consistency, apply mutual-exclusion if necessary and during debugging you can trap all accesses by setting break-points only in the access functions rather the *everywhere* access might otherwise occur.

You should perhaps read [A Pox on Globals](http://embedded.com/electronics-blogs/break-points/4025723/A-pox-on-globals) - it refers to embedded systems, but is no less applicable to desktop applications.

Comment: So, you suggest me that if I need to use a global data structure, I have to declare it static? I mean that in my case I need to have a global struct. Now I read what you linked me.

Comment: @Kyrol:  Well if it has static linkage, it is not truly global - so long as the only functions declared in the same translation unit are access functions and all other functions are in separate translation units to the global.  The point is to use separate compilation to encapsulate and limit the visibility of the variable.